# Headaches with configuring themed resources from c# (Windows Phone)

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have Windows Phone App and I want to have a different themed resources based on whether the user has a dark or light theme and which accent color they have chosen.

In my app initialize code I detect the users theme and accent color then load the appropriate Resource Dictionary, Dark, Light etc.  I add the Resource Dictionary to the  `App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries` collection.

The problem comes when I want to reference a value in the (dynamically loaded) from my App.Xaml. In the below example the key is "DefaultBackgroundImageOpacity".  For some reason the values in the ResourceDictionary that I load into the MergedDictionaries collection never get found when the App.Xaml parsing happens. I've played with loading the resources before I call InitializeComponent() and after. Neither seem to resolve the issue.

Any ideas?

```
// Simplified version of adding some xaml...
// Note I'm loading the key "DefaultBackgroundImageOpacity"
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();

var myTestXaml = "<ResourceDictionary xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' xmlns:System='clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib'> <System:Double x:Key='DefaultBackgroundImageOpacity'>0.2</System:Double></ResourceDictionary>";

this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(myTestXaml));

// This always fails saying that the key "DefaultBackgroundImageOpacity"
// can not be foudnd - even though it was loaded just above
InitializeComponent();

// Phone-specific initialization
InitializePhoneApplication();
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect your App.Xaml contains something like this:-

```
<Application.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="/somedictionary.xaml" />
          ...
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       ...
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If that is so then `InitializeComponent` will replace the default `ResourceDictionary` which you have manipulated in your code hence your changes to `MergeDictionaries` will not be present since that instance of a `ResourceDictionary` is no longer referenced.

If you are not setting up any `MergedDictionaries` in the App.Xaml then make sure you add resources directly to `Applicaiton.Resources` and are not creating an new instance of `ResourceDictionary` in the xaml.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  No I do not have the ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries in my app.xaml.   I'm just calling this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(...  Should I have an entry in app.xaml to make this work?

Comment: @Will: No the very opposite if you had such an enty in your app.xaml it would wipe out the modifications you had made the default instance of the resource dictionary.

Comment: OK. I ended up having to write code to "hand edit" all the places where I needed themed resources.  Seems like a core scenario but I just couldn't find the answer...