# Windows Phone 7: Global Resource Not Found

Tags: windows-phone-7, datatemplate, styles, resourcedictionary, windows-phone

I'm trying to use a global resource dictionary, but I'm getting an error when I try to use a style it contains. In my app.xaml I have:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ViewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"
                             d:IsDataSource="True" />
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="dict1">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/ListBox.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

The in /Themes/ListBox.xaml, I have this:

```
<Style x:Key="CategoryListTemplate" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
            ....
```

I'm trying to set the style with:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="lstCategories" SelectionMode="Extended" Style="{StaticResource CategoryListTemplate}" ...
```

Yet I get an error when the Viw is loading - "XamlParseException - Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key CategoryListTemplate [Line: 30 Position: 42]". Line 42 is the line which contains the listbox definition with `Style="{StaticResource CategoryListTemplate}"`.

The build action for LitBox.xaml is set to Resource, as far as I can tell this should work shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the following in App.xaml.cs instead:

```
var dictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
            dictionaries.Clear();
            var dicts = new[]{
                "/ChickenPing.Mobile;component/Themes/ThemeResources.xaml",
                "/ChickenPing.Mobile;component/Themes/generic.xaml",
                "/ChickenPing.Mobile;component/Themes/ListBox.xaml",
                "/ChickenPing.Mobile;component/Themes/Rating.xaml",
                "/ChickenPing.Mobile;component/Themes/CheckBox.xaml",
        };
            foreach (var dict in dicts) {
                var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary {Source = new Uri(dict, UriKind.Relative)};
                dictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418282/headaches-with-configuring-themed-resources-from-c-windows-phone/4437528#4437528).

It seems the phone doesn't support merging dictionaries in this way.